# Latest gnuplot for Windows 32

Tags: windows, compilation, gnuplot, binaries

There are no precompiled builds for Windows 32 bit for a long time. The links [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html) for Windows binaries provided erlier by Dr. Matsuoka are dead. I tried to compile from sources using Msys2 & mingw, but there are so many hidden and/or unobvious dependencies ... For me, not a programmer, it is very hard to wade through all these concise notes.

So, could anyone give me thorough instructions how to compile gnuplot for Windows, what and how should be preinstalled/configured.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have a 64bit windows machine at hand, why not learn how to build in 64bit first? Why don't you try 32bit after that?

Comment: @binzo, I think there is no great difference between 32 and 64 bit compilation. The essential question is how to build in Windows? I understand that gnuplot is primarily for Linux. It's a pity that developers abandon Windows versions, and provide no clear instructions for self-compilation.

Comment: For Windows 64bit, you might want to take a look at the following instruction and discussion on SourceForge. Support-Request([#199](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/support-requests/199/),[#256](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/support-requests/256/)).